# Differential Equations $ v \frac{dv}{dx} = -g \frac{a^2}{x^2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> > Question: A particle is projected vertically upwards from the Earth's surface. Its distance $x$ from the centre of the Earth is connected with its upwards speed $v$ by the differential equation:
> >
> > $$ v \frac{dv}{dx} = -g \frac{a^2}{x^2}$$ , where $a$ is the Earth's radius and g is a constant.
> >     If the initial speed at the Earth's surface is $v_0$, show that the maximum height to which the object rises is  $$ \frac{av_0^2}{2ga - v_0^2}$$

---

What I have attempted

$$ v \frac{dv}{dx} = -g \frac{a^2}{x^2}$$

$$ v dv = \frac{-ga^2}{x^2} dx $$

$$ \int v dv = -ga^2 \int \frac{1}{x^2} dx $$

$$ \int v dv = -ga^2 \int x^{-2} dx $$

$$ \frac {v^2}{2} = -ga^2\left( \frac{-1}{x} \right) + c $$

$$ \frac {v^2}{2} = \frac {ga^2}{x} + c $$

Rearranging to make x the subject

$$ \frac {v^2}{2} - c = \frac {ga^2}{x}  $$

$$ \frac {v^2}{2ga^2} - \frac{c}{ga^2} = x$$

at $x=0$ , $v=v_0$

$$ \frac {v_0^2}{2ga^2} - \frac{c}{ga^2} = 0 $$

$$ c = \frac{v_0^2}{2} $$

$$ x = \frac {v^2}{2ga^2} - \frac{v_0^2}{2ga^2} $$

How do I continue this (If I got the above correct)?

Comment: Hint: at the maximum height, the speed is equal to zero. The initial height is $
x=a$ and not $x=0$ (center of Earth).

Comment: The solving for $x$ has an error. Also the $x$ at the beginning is $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly solved for your constant. At the time of launch, $v=v_o$ and $x=a$. Thus:

$\displaystyle\frac {v_0^2}{2} = \frac {ga^2}{a} + c$

$c=\displaystyle\frac {v_0^2-2ga}{2}$

Substituting $c$ back into our equation we have:

$\displaystyle\frac {v^2}{2} = \frac {ga^2}{x} + \frac {v_0^2-2ga}{2}$

Letting $v=0$ and solving for $x:$

$\displaystyle0 = \frac {ga^2}{x} + \frac {v_0^2-2ga}{2}$

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

When you are integrating just substitute the appropriate limits. $$\int_{v_0}^0 v dv = -ga^2 \int_a^{h_{max}} x^{-2} dx$$ Following this you get the desired expression.